# Instagram API: $value->location->latitude outputs comma separated value, whereas Google Maps accepts dot

Tags: replace, preg-replace, str-replace, json, instagram

`$value->location->latitude` and `$value->location->longitude` output respectively something like 41,90693866 and 12,414128943. I have a link which points to

```
href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q='.htmlentities($value->location->latitude).',+'.htmlentities($value->location->longitude).'"
```

Problem is Google Maps accepts values like 41.90693866 (notice dot instead of comma), it doesn't work with 41,90693866, 12,414128943 input (it does with 41.90693866, 12.414128943). How can I output latitude/longitude with comma instead of dot?

Answer (score 0):

The json data that I see with the Instagram API uses periods and not commas with the lat/lng data. Are you sure something in your code is not transforming the formatting? Check your code for this.

Comment: Uhm, you're right. JSON has the dot. Anyway I'm not transforming the formatting.. :o Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/3t8Jj9qP